# Applying cumulative correction factor across dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fairly new to Pandas so please forgive me if the answer to my question is rather obvious. I've got a dataset like this

```
    Data Correction
0   100  Nan
1   104  Nan
2   108  Nan
3   112  Nan
4   116  Nan
5   120  0.5
6   124  Nan
7   128  Nan
8   132  Nan
9   136  0.4
10  140  Nan
11  144  Nan
12  148  Nan
13  152  0.3
14  156  Nan
15  160  Nan
```

What I want to is to calculate the correction factor for the data which accumulates upwards.

By that I mean that elements from `13` and below should have the factor `0.3` applied, with `9` and below applying `0.3*0.4` and `5` and below `0.3*0.4*0.5`.

So the final correction column should look like this

```
    Data  Correction  Factor
0   100   Nan         0.06
1   104   Nan         0.06
2   108   Nan         0.06
3   112   Nan         0.06
4   116   Nan         0.06
5   120   0.5         0.06
6   124   Nan         0.12
7   128   Nan         0.12
8   132   Nan         0.12
9   136   0.4         0.12
10  140   Nan         0.3
11  144   Nan         0.3
12  148   Nan         0.3
13  152   0.3         0.3
14  156   Nan         1
15  160   Nan         1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You mean "above" everywhere right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`cumprod()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html) after reversing the  `Correction` column:

```
df=df.assign(Factor=df.Correction[::-1].cumprod().ffill().fillna(1))
```

---

```
    Data  Correction  Factor
0    100         NaN    0.06
1    104         NaN    0.06
2    108         NaN    0.06
3    112         NaN    0.06
4    116         NaN    0.06
5    120         0.5    0.06
6    124         NaN    0.12
7    128         NaN    0.12
8    132         NaN    0.12
9    136         0.4    0.12
10   140         NaN    0.30
11   144         NaN    0.30
12   148         NaN    0.30
13   152         0.3    0.30
14   156         NaN    1.00
15   160         NaN    1.00
```

Comment: Thanks very much for such a prompt reply

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a good pandas function that does this, however, you can create a for loop to do multiply an array with the values then put it as a column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

lst = [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,0.5,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,0.4,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,0.3,np.nan,np.nan]
lst1 = [i + 100 for i in range(len(lst))]
newcol= [1.0 for i in range(len(lst))]
newcol = np.asarray(newcol)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data' : lst1,'Correction' : lst})
for i in range(len(df['Correction'])):
  if(~np.isnan(df.Correction[i])):
    print(df.Correction[i])
    newcol[0:i+1] = newcol[0:i+1] * df.Correction[i]
df['Factor'] = newcol
print(df)
```

This code prints

```
Data  Correction  Factor
0    100         NaN    0.06
1    101         NaN    0.06
2    102         NaN    0.06
3    103         NaN    0.06
4    104         NaN    0.06
5    105         0.5    0.06
6    106         NaN    0.12
7    107         NaN    0.12
8    108         NaN    0.12
9    109         NaN    0.12
10   110         0.4    0.12
11   111         NaN    0.30
12   112         NaN    0.30
13   113         NaN    0.30
14   114         0.3    0.30
15   115         NaN    1.00
16   116         NaN    1.00
```